# How do I make a Div that has round corners and a background colour?

Tags: css, html, background-color, rounded-corners

When I assign "background-color: foo;" to a  element in my CSS file I do not get any colour. What other attributes do i need to declare, I have a absolute width set? Does it need a parent container (it has a basic  as a parent)? What am I missing here?!

Also I'd like to give it round-corners using HTML5. Corners only have to work in Safari as it's for a web app not general consumption.

Comment: The web is full of round-corners DIV guides. What have you tried?

Comment: What are you suggesting I try? I can post my code but it looks like the ones below, <head-scratch>.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems you have 2 questions:
1. set background to an element; 2. you wanna set round corners to an element and works in safari.

1. if you element is div tag, you need to set width,and height of your div tag, e.g:

   `<div id='mydiv'>some elements here</div>`

Your css:

```
   #mydiv { 
      background-color: #111;
      height: 100px;
      width:100px
   }
```

2. Setting round-corner(code below works for all browsers):

```
   .round-corner {
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px; 
      -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
      -o-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
      border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
   }
```

Comment: I want the height to be dynamic, can I leave off the height and just let the elements stretch it?

Comment: @wide_eyed_pupil: yes you can

Answer (score 1):

Background color has to be in hex or a valid string recognizable by the browser

So, something like this:

`background: #F0F0F0;`

or

`background: white;`

For borders:

`border-radius: 4px;`

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ncVBh/1/)**